# how to have svn fetch a file from another directory on updates?

Tags: svn

I have two repository folder. One in which the build.dll is set.
There is another folder which needs this dll up to date. What I'd like to do is when I update the second directory on my computer, it would fetch the build.dll from the other one. So no physical copy in the second directory.

We have Windows 7 at work.

Comment: provide more details about environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subversion calls these types of relationships "[externals](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.externals.html)".  You just need to set the `svn:externals` property on the second directory so that SVN will pull down the external file when the second directory is updated.

To set this property, run a command similar to this (on Windows):

```
svn propset svn:externals "^/trunk/path/to/build.dll build.dll" your/second/directory
```

Or, if you're using TortoiseSVN, the built-in editor is quite a bit more user-friendly.  See details [here](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-externals.html).

Comment: thanks a lot for the quick answer. May I ask where I set this command so it is runned un update of the specified folder?

Comment: You run the command once.  It will add this property to the specified folder, and then you commit this folder.  Then, every time this folder is updated it will pull down the external file.